# How to select unique {key, last value} from html table with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a html table likes:

```
<table border="1">
　<tr>
　<td>apple</td>
　<td>10</td>
　</tr>
　<tr>
　<td>apple</td>
　<td>7</td>
　</tr>
　<tr>
　<td>banana</td>
　<td>8</td>
　</tr>
　<tr>
　<td>apple</td>
　<td>9</td>
　</tr>
　<tr>
　<td>cat</td>
　<td>11</td>
　</tr>
　<tr>
　<td>banana</td>
　<td>7</td>
　</tr>
　<tr>
　<td>cat</td>
　<td>2</td>
　</tr>
</table>
```

[image]

How should I aggregate this table on a column?

For this example, aggregate table by column one, and the last value related to that key in the table.

[image]

Comment: If you haven't tried anything yet then start by learning javascript.

Comment: Post what you have tried so far [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please put your exact requirements in word with example.

Comment: I don't think this question should be about filters, the subject should contain pivot, aggregate, or group by

Comment: use  `mytable = document.getElementById("my-table"); mytable.rows[1].cells[1].textContent; ...`

Answer (score 0):

Created a method referring to [this](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_filter_table.asp) post. Hope this will be helpful.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length - 1; i++) { //Excluding last row
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    if (td) {
      txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
      if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
Search First Columns 
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search all table" title="Type in a name" />

<table id="myTable" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>apple</td>
    <td>10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>apple</td>
    <td>7</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>banana</td>
    <td>8</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>apple</td>
    <td>9</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>cat</td>
    <td>11</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>banana</td>
    <td>7</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>cat</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @Pygirl your requirement is to search the table by first column and keeping the last row. Right?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I didn't truly understand your filtration requirement, but what I understood is you want to filter based on certain requirements.
So always try to add filtration logic at JS side, not on the HTML.
Hence you can maintain this at JS like below code example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  this.json = {
    "Students": [{
        "id": "1",
        "hometown": "London",
        "gender": "Male",
        "GPA": "8",
        "name": "Lee",
      },
      {
        "id": "2",
        "hometown": "NY",
        "gender": "Male",
        "GPA": "9",
        "name": "Shaldon",
      }, {
        "id": "3",
        "hometown": "Paris",
        "gender": "Female",
        "GPA": "7",
        "name": "Julie",
      }
    ]
  };
  
  this.renderTable = function(Students) {
    var tbody = document.getElementById('tbody');
    tbody.innerHTML = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < Students.length; i++) {
      var tr = "<tr>";
      tr += "<td>ID</td>" + "<td>" + Students[i].id + "</td></tr>";
      tr += "<td>HomeTown</td>" + "<td>" + Students[i].hometown + "</td></tr>";
      tr += "<td>Gender</td>" + "<td>" + Students[i].gender + "</td></tr>";
      tr += "<td>GPA</td>" + "<td>" + Students[i].GPA + "</td></tr>";
      tr += "<td>NAME</td>" + "<td>" + Students[i].name + "</td></tr>";
      tr += "<hr>";
      tbody.innerHTML += tr;
    }
  }

  this.renderTable(this.json.Students);

  console.log(this.json.Students);
  //code for filtering//
  this.Filter = function() {
    var search = document.getElementById('search');
    var category = document.getElementById('category');
    var filteredObj = this.json.Students;
    filteredObj = $.map(this.json.Students, function(val, key) {
      if (search.value === val[category.value]) return val;
    });
    filteredObj.length>0 ? this.renderTable(filteredObj) : this.renderTable(this.json.Students);
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p></p>

<input id="search" type="search">
<select id = "category">
<option value = "select">select</option>
   <option value = "id">ID</option>
   <option value = "hometown">HomeTown</option>
   <option value = "gender">Gender</option>
   <option value = "GPA">GPA</option>
   <option value = "name">NAME</option>
  </select>
<button onclick="Filter()">Filter</button>

<table>
  <tbody id="tbody"></tbody>
</table>
```